# Tomato plant's leaves have white lines on them

Tags: identification, plant-health, leaves, tomatoes, insects

This is my first time gardening, and I noticed the other day, one of my tomato plant's leave started looking a bit odd. I haven't fertilized any of the plants yet, as this is my first time, and I honestly don't know when the right time to do so is. So just wondering what can be done to get the leaves back to normal.

Thank you so much!
-Pamela [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PC51c.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

It's a little hard to tell from the photo because we can't get a close-up view of the leaves, but it looks like your plant has tomato leaf miner. See [here](https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-LSMOeqsfJV4/UCsl9nDcl0I/AAAAAAAAHDA/WM9_1EN1tYk/s1600/LeafMiner.jpg) for a photo that you can use to compare to your plant. If your plant does have miners, this [site](https://www2.ipm.ucanr.edu/agriculture/tomato/leafminers/) has some instructions for controlling them. Note that you don't want to drench the area in insecticides, as you will kill beneficial insects that also feed on the miners. An organic alternative to the pesticides listed in the linked site is spinosad.

In the fall, remove ALL tomato leaves and stems from your garden to help reduce fungal diseases and insect infestations next year. Also, you need to rotate your tomatoes (and peppers, egg plants, and potatoes, if you grow them) each year to a different part of vegetable garden; a three-year rotation is usually recommended. This is to reduce diseases (all the plants I listed are in the same family and can therefore get the same diseases).

Comment: I concur that it looks like leaf miners. Giving plants plenty of sun is one way to help deter leaf miners.